# TypeError: res.status(...).sendFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, express

I'm a beginner at this stuff so I apologize if this is an easy fix. But I'm getting the error below.

```
TypeError: res.status(...).sendFile is not a function
    at app.get (/root/discordtest/server.js:10:19)
    at callbacks (/root/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/root/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/root/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/root/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router [as handle] (/root/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/root/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
    at next (/root/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:149:78)
    at Object.expressInit [as handle] (/root/node_modules/express/lib/middleware.js:30:5)
    at next (/root/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
```

The code that I am using is:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

// Routes
app.use('/api/discord', require('./api/discord'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(50451, () => {
  console.info('Running on port 50451');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your versions. 
res.sendFile() is supported by Express v4.8.0 onwards

Comment: I'm currently using the latest Express version; 6.4.1

Comment: Check your path- res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));